# Use COALESCE (or something like it) with GROUP BY in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think I'm missing something basic in how to efficiently use GROUP BY to eliminate redundant records.  I keep hitting places where it seems like I need to use COALESCE, except that as best I can tell that doesn't work with GROUP BY.

Example: I have a table with table with each combination of visitID and visitBillingCode, along with other useful info:

```
VisitID    SearchRank1    SearchRank2   BillingID
--------------------------------------------------
1          34             NULL          3432
1          34             NULL          3467
2          27             8             3280
2          29             NULL          2903
```

I would like to collapse this down so that I have only one row per VisitID.  Conveniently, I would even be happy to take just the largest non-null value of the other columns whenever there are multiple rows in play, so that I ended up with something like this:

```
VisitID    SearchRank1    SearchRank2   BillingID
--------------------------------------------------
1          34             NULL          3467
2          29             8             3280
```

It seems like this should be obtainable with something like this:

```
SELECT VisitID, 
       COALESCE(SearchRank1) AS SearchRank1, 
       COALESCE(SearchRank2) AS SearchRank2,
       MAX(BillingID) AS BillingID
FROM Db.Table1
GROUP BY VisitID
```

But when I try it, I get an error in the coalesce lines, and I'm thinking this is just because I can't actually use coalesce with group by.  Is this correct?  If so, what is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `max()` or `min()`:

```
SELECT VisitID, 
       MAX(SearchRank1) AS SearchRank1, 
       MAX(SearchRank2) AS SearchRank2,
       MAX(BillingID) AS BillingID
FROM Db.Table1
GROUP BY VisitID;
```

`COALESCE()` is not an aggregation function.  But, aggregation functions generally ignore `NULL` values, so they have a similar effect.

You would use `COALESCE()` for something like:

```
select VisitId, coalesce(SearchRank2, SearchRank1)
from db.table1;
```

Comment: Ah.  I now see why I was confused by noone else was having this problem, as well - I somehow had it in my head that I should avoid this solution because MAX/MIN would do odd things if there were only NULL values, but I see now I that that's where I was wrong.  Thank you!